# How do I convert JSON values into a key value pair pir

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON in the following format and need to convert the 2 values into a Key / Value pair in javascript

"column_values": [
{
"id": "status",
"text": "Working on it"
}
]

I need the result to be

"column_values"[{"status": "Working on it"}]

I need the code to iterate through the column_values array and convert all the sets of id and text pairs to the key = id value : Value = text:values

Is my result possible?

Additional Information...

I am parsing a response from monday.com api in zapier.

the api payload is contained in

const results = response.json;

the full api payload is

```
{
  "data": {
    "boards": [
      {
        "name": "Test Board",
        "items": [
          {
            "name": "Name Change",
            "id": "625495642",
            "column_values": [
              {
                "id": "person",
                "text": ""
              },
              {
                "id": "subitems",
                "text": "Subitem 1, Subitem 2"
              },
              {
                "id": "status",
                "text": "Working on it"
              },
              {
                "id": "dropdown",
                "text": "Test1"
              },
              {
                "id": "formula",
                "text": ""
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "account_id": 1111
}
```

I need to the the code to parse the data and replace the column_values with the format above, and then pass the reformated payload to

return results;

Comment: please post some sample input, output, and what you have attempted yet.

Answer (score 1):

You just Map the Array you start out with to an Array with the values.

```js
var column_values = [ { "id": "status", "text": "Working on it" } ]

var KeyValuePairs = column_values.map(cv => [cv.id,cv.text]);

console.log(KeyValuePairs);
```

Answer (score 0):

If every object is going to contain the `id` and `text` keys only, you can map it and delete the other keys.

```js
column_values = column_values.map(item => {
  item[item.id] = item.text;
  delete item.id;
  delete item.text;
  return item;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
var column_values = [ { "id": "status", "text": "Working on it" } ]
var res = column_values.map(x => ({[x.id] : x.text}))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Hi 
Thanks this worked  and when through the list to return the pairs I need.

The

Comment: glad that helped you; dont forget to mark as solved

Comment: Sorry I am new to stackoverflow and still navigating how to use it  - I have added additional information to the problem.

Comment: i dont know anything about this api but you can access it like this : a.data.boards[0].items[0].column_values

Comment: Sorry I am lost . How do I use your solution on the JSON in the results variable? I am not looking for help in the API just how to change the values in the JSON payload.

Comment: assign the return of the api to a variable (var res ), then try this:

var data = res.data.boards[0].items.reduce((acc, y) => y.column_values.map(cv => [cv.id,cv.text]))